# Angularjs object found in $window but cannot access it in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I have a node module with the following schema (excerpt):

```
email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    required: 'Please fill in a username',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
    match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
},
token: {},
password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    },
salt: {
        type: String
    },
```

now I have an object going into token, which is fine. But now I'm trying to access the token and this is giving me problems.

I have an Authentication service with the following code:

```
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [ '$http',  '$state', '$location',
    function($http, $state, $location) {

        var _this = this;
        var _user_exists = {};

        _this._data = {
            user: window.user
        };

    return _this;
}
```

]);

which is picking up the user object from the window.

I'm embedding the object using:

```
<!--Embedding The User Object-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var user = {{ user | json | safe }};
            console.log(user); //the token object data is in here
    </script>
```

However, when I assign it in another controller using:

```
$scope.user = Authentication._data.user;//the token object data NOT here
```

I'm not seeing the token object data.

The strange thing is that all the other data come up ok - its just the token data.

On a POSTMAN query, I can see that all the token object data is there.

Can anyone help?

Comment: try not use _this_ inside factory. Just simple `return {_data : {
            user: window.user
        };}; `

Comment: `this` in a factory in your case will be window, factory is not instantiated with `new` operator unlike the service.

Comment: Hi PSL - apoloigies but could you elaborate a little?